# create card using array of data react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, array-map

> hi everyone I have data  given below by using this data I just want to create a cart   [click on this link to check what kind of cart I want to design from this data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f9gc.png)

```
 const result = [
{
  name: 'shanu',
  label: ['ak', 'pk', 'plk', 'k'],
  value: [1, 2, 3, 5],
},
```

];

// what i did

```js
 {result.map((el) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>{el.name}</h1>
            <div className="vart">
              <div>
                {el.label.map((e) => {
                  return <p>{e}</p>;
                })}
              </div>
              <div>
                {el.value.map((e) => {
                  return <p>{e}</p>;
                })}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
```

```css
.vart {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Comment: Hello, have you tried to run you code step by step? Take a look at map function with ReactJs on the web. Also if you can edit your question and make it more comfortable for reading. Thanks!

Comment: I still dont know what ur asking? Do you get an error?

Comment: I just  want to create a cart like an image assign  with question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `value` according to the `index` of the label as below. You can use a [CSS grid system](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) to show a two-column view.

```
export default function App() {
  const result = [
    {
      name: "shanu",
      label: ["ak", "pk", "plk", "k"],
      value: [1, 2, 3, 5]
    }
  ];

  return result.map((el) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="header">{el.name}</div>
        <div className="grid-container">
          {el.label.map((e, index) => {
            return (
              <div
                className="grid-item"
                style={{ textAlign: index % 2 === 0 ? "left" : "right" }}
              >
                {e} : {el.value[index]}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

Following styles will organise the grid with right aligning the second column.

```
.header {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #4473c4;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #91cf50;
}
```

##### HTML Output

[image]

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-buck-rytpq?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @Shanu Singh, check this out !!

Comment: @Shanu Singh, I have updated the code sandbox with styles as well

Comment: tnx bro I checked it already, and how you did that is totally appreciable

Answer (score 0):

If you want to link value and label this way:

```
ak => 1
pk => 2
plk => 3
k => 5
```

It would be better practice to change your data structure and move them aside. It avoids running in cases where `label[x]` is defined, but `value[x]` is not:

```
export default function App() {
  const result = [
    {
      name: "shanu",
      items: [
        { label: "ak", value: 1 },
        { label: "pk", value: 2 },
        { label: "plk", value: 3 },
        { label: "k", value: 5 },
      ],
    }
  ];

  return result.map((el) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{el.name}</h1>
        <div className="vart">
          <div>
            {el.items.map((e, index) => {
              return (
                <p>
                  {e.label} : {e.value}
                </p>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: tnx bro, but what I want Amila Senadheera  updated solution for that